# Excel VBA code exits unexpectedly, certainly related to: "a function call on the left side of assignment should return Variant or Object"

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, variable-assignment

Here is my code:

```
Public Function get_best(cell As Variant, Optional threshold = 0.5) As String
    Dim res As String
    Dim Rate As Double
    Lines = Split(cell.Value, vbCr)
    res = ""
    Tag = "[C : "
    For i = LBound(Lines, 1) To UBound(Lines, 1)
        pos = InStr(Lines(i), Tag)
        If pos > 0 Then
            pos1 = pos + Len(Tag) + 1
            pos2 = InStr(pos1, Lines(i), "%]")
            sRate = Mid(Lines(i), pos1, pos2 - pos1)
            Rate = CDec(sRate)
            If Rate >= threshold Then
                res = res & Lines(i) & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    get_best = res
End Function
```

Here is an example of cell on which to apply it, say A1:

```
[C : 5.1%] azerty
    aaa bbb ccc 
[C : 0.2%] qwerty
    ddd eee fff
```

Then a call:

```
= get_best(A1)
```

Expected result:

```
[C : 5.1%] azerty
```

What it does is:

- Parse the lines in the cell passed as argument
- Throw all lines that do not contain the tag
- For the lines containing the tag, returns the ones where the percentage value after the tag is superior to the threshold passed as argument

It fails:

- With debugger, I can see it silently exit function at line `Rate = CDec(sRate)`
- If I suppress `Dim Rate As Double` then I have the error (translated from french): `compilation error: a function call on the left side of assignment should return Variant or Object`

I don't understand this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your first issue is that your variable `pos1` is off by 1, therefore `sRate` gets `.1` instead of `5.1`. The function `CDec` doesn't like that and throws an error that it cannot convert this to a Double. If you correct that, it will work.

Your second issue is that `Rate` is a build-in function in VBA. When you declare you variable `rate` as Double, you will hide the function and the VBA runtime knows that you want to use a variable. If you don't define it, it will assume you are accessing the function, and you can't assing a value to a function, therefore the compiler error. But if you fix this, you will still get the conversion error.

Minor issue: You will likely need to split by `vbLf`, not by `vbCr`.

You should, by the way, use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, `pos1` corrected, `Rate` renamed, but the problem is still here. When I stop on `fRate = CDec(sRate)` in debug mode and spy `CDec(sRate)`, it says `value = Incompatible type` and `Type = Variant/Integer` though I have added `sRate`declaration: `Dim res, sRate As String`

Comment: If I change `fRate = CDec(sRate)` by `fRate = 0.6`, everything is fine. So the problem is with ` CDec(sRate)`

Comment: ok, it is a locale issue, `fRate = CDec("0.6")` fails, `fRate = CDec("0,6")` go

Comment: Adding `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."` and `Application.UseSystemSeparators = False` does not work. I am going to substitute '.' by ','

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was a locale one: The input data for CDEC shall use the same decimal separator than the one of your locale e.g. if in your locale the decimal separator is a comma `','` and if your input data uses the dot `'.'` then you have to convert your data with `Replace(sRate, ".", ",")`.

Final code is:

```
Public Function get_best(cell As Variant, Optional threshold = 0.5) As String
    Dim res, sRate As String
    Dim fRate As Double
    Lines = Split(cell.Value, vbLf)
    res = ""
    Tag = "[Couverture : "
    For i = LBound(Lines, 1) To UBound(Lines, 1)
        pos = InStr(Lines(i), Tag)
        If pos > 0 Then
            pos1 = pos + Len(Tag) + 1
            pos2 = InStr(pos1, Lines(i), "%]")
            sRate = Mid(Lines(i), pos1, pos2 - pos1)
            fRate = CDbl(Replace(sRate, ".", ","))
            If fRate >= threshold Then
                res = res & Lines(i) & vbLf
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    get_best = res
End Function
```